# Python: Indexing the left side and right side of an assignment

Tags: python, assignment-operator

I'm trying to do something simple like the following

```
for k in range(0,2)

outsetk = Reader(FileName='/dir/outset-'+str(k)+'.q')
```

to generate the following

```
outset0 = Reader(FileName='/dir/outset-'+str(0)+'.q')
outset1 = Reader(FileName='/dir/outset-'+str(1)+'.q')
outset2 = Reader(FileName='/dir/outset-'+str(2)+'.q')
```

where Reader is some predefined function with only one input. I know the right side of the assignment is correct but I'm not sure how to do the left side.

Comment: Use a list or a dictionary, not separate variables.

Comment: How would I generate the list of variables of list = [outset0,outset1,outset2,...] with a for loop?

Comment: Using `list.append()` each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a dictionary to hold the results. Something like this:

```
outsets = {}

for k in range(0, 3):
    outsets[k] = Reader(FileName='/dir/outset-' + str(k) + '.q')
```

Then you would access `outset0` like so:

```
outsets[0] # equivalent to your outset0
```

You could also do something like this to get the same names mentioned in your example:

```
outsets = {}
name = 'outset{}'

for k in range(0, 3):
    outsets[name.format(k)] = Reader(FileName='/dir/outset-' + str(k) + '.q')
```

To access `outset0` you would use `outsets['outset0']`

If you wanted to use a list instead, try something like this:

```
outsets = []

for k in range(0, 3):
     outsets.append(Reader(FileName='/dir/outset-' + str(k) + '.q')
```

Then you would access `outset0` the same way:

```
 outsets[0] # equivalent to your outset0
```